# jmeter Cannot find interface error

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I'm trying to run an test on jmeter. However, when I'm run an test I'm getting the following result: Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException/Non HTTP response message: Cannot find interface ec2-**-**-**-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Why would I get the following error message when I'm trying to do an load test? I'm running jmeter from the desktop and I'm trying to an load test from the site from the AWS.

Thank you,
Kevin Davis

Comment: can you show full stacktrace in jmeter.log and show the concerned http request in JMeter ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the resolution. It was an advance setting of the http request defaults that was causing the issue.

Comment: What was the setting?

Comment: @K Davis what was the issu?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to do [IP spoofing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter) using wrong settings, you should not be using your AWS instance hostname in the `Source address` tab, it should be rather [network adapter](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/8546/network-adapter) name, you can get it using i.e. [ifconfig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig) command.

[image: IfConfig Interface Name]

Once you determine network adapter name - substitute your `ec2----*.compute-1.amazonaws.com` with the real adapter name, i.e. `eth0`

[image: JMeter IP Spoofing Device Name]

---

If you are not going to use the IP Spoofing - just leave this `Source address` field blank.